# Destructor in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, destructor

Below is the code. I did not manually `del` object reference but then also in VScode `__del__` gets invoked. But the same piece of code is working in Jupyter Notebook. This means, `__del__` is not called automatically. Is there any problem with the code? Confused. Does VScode handle Garbage Collector (automatically)? Googled a lot, but did not get an appropriate answer.

```
class Student:
    # constructor
    def __init__(self, name):
        print('Inside Constructor')
        self.name = name
        print('Object initialized')

    def show(self):
        print('Hello, my name is', self.name)

    # destructor
    def __del__(self):
        print('Inside destructor')
        print('Object destroyed')

# create object
s1 = Student('Emma')
s2 = s1;
s3 = s1;
print("Id of S1: " , id(s1));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to call `__del__` a finalizer method because this method gets called exactly when the object is about to be garbage collected. (like when all references to that object are gone.)

In VSCode or even when you run your script in terminal, when the interpreter reaches the end of the file it will terminate the execution and the process, therefore any objects will be destroyed. So you can see that this method gets called. So even if you didn't `del` the references to the object explicitly, all the references will be gone at the end.

Jupyter notebook on the other hand is still running, and also maybe it keeps a reference to your object for internal works...

Put a simple `input()` in the last line of your code, you can see that the `__del__` wont get called in VScode or terminal as well.